# Changing font size options in QGIS Layout Manager

Tags: qgis, labeling, font

I am trying to create a title block in the layout manager in QGIS 3.10, using labels to create text. However, when I try to adjust the font size in Item Properties, I would like more flexibility in font size. As in, I would like to be able to use decimal font sizes rather than the whole numbers available. Is there some way to tinker with the settings to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

You can set a decimal font size using the dropdown icon instead of opening `Text Format` window.

[image]